# How to write files received in @MultipartConfig HttpServlet into the specific folder?

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, multipartconfig

i am sending both `files and other fields data` to servlet using ajax `FormData append()` as follows:

html

```
<form   id="formId1" >
   <input type="file" name="file" id="fileid">
   <input type="text" name="t1" id="d">
   <input type="submit" id="btn" value="submit">
</form>
```

ajax call:

```
  $("#btn").click(function(event){ 
                  event.preventDefault(); 
                  var fd = new FormData();
      var other_data = $('form').serializeArray();
                    $.each(other_data,function(key,input){
                        fd.append("t1",$("#d").val());
                      fd.append("file",$('#fileid').prop('files')[0])
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'Sample1',
                        data: fd,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });     });
```

and i used `@MultipartConfig` to read both `files and other data`

```
@WebServlet("/Sample1")
@MultipartConfig
public class Sample1 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    { 

        String s=request.getParameter("t1");
        System.out.println(s); 
        Part part=request.getPart("file");
        File path =new File("path")// HOW TO PUT PART INTO THE FOLDER
        }}
```

now am not able to store that part as image into the folder
how to get `folder or images` from `Part` please help me this.

Comment: This might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824. In particular "To browse and select a file for upload you need a HTML <input type="file"> field in the form. As stated in the HTML specification you have to use the POST method and the enctype attribute of the form has to be set to "multipart/form-data""

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @ Tom Mac in that link ,its not showing how to store image to  folder

Answer (score 0):

this code will store file into destination folder

```
@WebServlet("/Sample1")
@MultipartConfig
public class Sample1 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    { 

                String jj=request.getParameter("t1");
                System.out.println(jj); 


            //GETTING FILE
                Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); 
            //GETTING FILE NAME
                String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();  

                InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();

                    File file1 =new File("D:\\Projects\\i_seva\\WebContent\\"+fileName+"."+"png");
                    BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(fileContent);

                    ImageIO.write(imBuff, "png", file1); 

                    System.out.println(fileName); 

    }   

}
```

thank you friends i did it with help of stack over flow members suggested links and posts